# Spring-Ldap active directory authentication not working

Tags: java, authentication, active-directory, spring-ldap

I am trying to authenticate active directory using spring ldap, this code works exactly for open ldap but it's not working for Microsoft Active directory here is exception while authenticating:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.ldap.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A8, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1
```

**code:**

```
public class Main {
private LdapTemplate ldapTemplate;
private ContextSource contextSource;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main main = new Main();
    main.initialize();
    main.authenticate();
}

private void initialize() {
    LdapContextSource lcs = new LdapContextSource();
    lcs.setUrl("ldap://52.187.56.263:389/");
    lcs.setUserDn("cn=shoukathmd,dc=xyz,dc=com");
    lcs.setPassword("Admin12345678");
    lcs.setDirObjectFactory(DefaultDirObjectFactory.class);
    lcs.afterPropertiesSet();
    ldapTemplate = new LdapTemplate(lcs);
    contextSource = lcs;
}

public boolean authenticate() {
    DirContext ctx = null;
    try {
        ldapTemplate.authenticate(query().base("dc=xyz,dc=com").where("mail").is("shoukathmd@xyz.com"), "Admin12345678");
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Context creation failed - authentication did not succeed
        //logger.error("Login failed", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } finally {
        // It is imperative that the created DirContext instance is always closed
        LdapUtils.closeContext(ctx);
    }
}
}
```

[image: Active Directory]

Comment: A complete stack trace would make it easier to figure out exactly what goes wrong here.

Comment: try using lcs.setUserDn("shoukathmd@xyz.com");